# invalid extent - grub rescue

Tags: 12.04, grub2, external-hdd, grubrescue

**TRANSLATION**

I've **Ubuntu 12.04** and **ArtistX** on a **laptop** with a **external HDD**. These work great.

After this I installed these in two PC and I get the next message on both:

```
-error: invalid extent.  grub rescue-.
```

I used `CD SuperGrub` and tried all their options and it doesn't work.

On the laptop the GRUB is on the external disk and I wanted the same for the PC's.

If anyone know the reason of why happens this, I'll appreciate.

**TEXTO ORIGINAL**

Tengo instalado en un portátil sobre un disco externo Ubuntu 12.04 y ArtistX, y van de maravilla.
Pero mi sorpresa es que después de cogerle el gustillo lo fui a instalar en dos PCs de sobremesa, ambos distintos, y lo único que consigo es

```
-error: invalid extent.  grub rescue-.
```

He recurrido al CD SuperGrub, y probado todas las opciones y no hay manera.

En el portátil el GRUB esta en el disco externo y quería que fuese así en los de sobremesa.

Si alguien conoce la causa de porque pueda pasar esto, se lo agradecería.

Comment: Deberías reparar el GRUB en esos dos equipos en los que tienes problemas. Puedes reparar el GRUB con Boot-Repair, [en este link](http://www.ayudapc.com/problemas-de-software/7613-grub-rescue-mode-2.html#post30000) explico como hacerlo

Answer (score -1):

Muy agradecido por la contestación.
Mi problema no es no poder arrancar W7 sino arrancar UBUNTU.
Hice lo siguiente.-Grabe desde el CD de instalacion una memoria de stick, para crear un pendrive de instalación con el programa de 'crear disco de arranque'.
Luego con este pendrive instalé de nuevo Ubuntu, en el ordenador elegí multiarranque de la BIOS, seleccioné mi disco HDD USB y maravilla esta vez funcionó, me salió GRUB con las opciones de Linux y W7, estando el Grub grabado esta vez correctamente en HDD USB.
Pero mi ilusión duró poco, despues de actualizar, a la hora de reiniciar me volvió a machacar el GRUB, hablo de la versión 12.04, y la actualización del SO 27. 
Esto me hace suponer que es claramente algo que ha dejado de funcionar a la hora de la acualización con el Grub.

Piensos que el GRUB en los ordenadores modernos, con multiarranque, si Usas Discos duros externos no tenga mucha razon de ser, ya que  bastaría con hacerlos bootables. De hecho ahora que he comenzado a probar Linux, hubo una distro que por desgracia no recuerdo, que a la hora de la instalación me preguntaba si quería instalar Grub o Lilo -no recuerdo cual- dándome la opción de instalarlo o saltarlo.

De todas formas muy muy agradecido.
Luis